# Searchable keywords in Perforce?

Tags: search, perforce, keyword

In Perforce there seems to be no way to attach searchable keywords to a file, so that users can look for files without knowing their locations or names. Is there any other feature that might be used the same way?

Note I'm asking about a way to search for keywords that are *attached to* a file, not *found in* a file. The files I need to find generally are binary, so storing keywords in them would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this (as far as what's built directly into Perforce) would be `p4 index`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help index

    index -- Add words to the jobs index (unsupported)

    p4 index [-a attrib] [-d] name

        Index is an interface to the search engine used to search jobs.
        It reads its standard input for text, breaks the text into words,
        and adds those words to the search engine's index with the
        key 'name' and the optional attribute 'attrib'.  (Job fields
        are entered with the name of the job as the name and the field
        name as the attribute.)

        If -a attrib is specified, that attribute number is used instead of 0.

        The -d option deletes entries from the index.

        See also 'p4 help search'.
```

So you can do:

```
C:\Perforce\test>echo "cute doggo" | p4 index //depot/puppies.jpg
2 words added/deleted.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 search doggo
//depot/puppies.jpg
```

Note that the path `//depot/puppies.jpg` is really just an arbitrary string/ID, and isn't tied to an actual depot file/revision (e.g. it won't "follow" the file if it gets renamed or integrated).

If you want something that's attached to a file in a more meaningful way, you might want to look at `p4 attribute -p`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help attribute

    attribute -- Set per-revision attributes on revisions

    p4 attribute [-e -f -p] -n name [-v value] files...
    p4 attribute [-e -f -p] -i -n name file

        Sets a user-managed attribute 'name' to 'value' on opened files.
        If -v is omitted, the attribute is cleared (if set).

        To display attributes use 'p4 fstat -Oa'.

        The -e flag indicates that the 'value' is specified in hex.

        The -f flag sets the attribute on submitted files.  If a propagating
        trait is set on a submitted file, a revision specification may not
        be used, and the file must not be currently open on any client.
        The -f flag requires 'admin' access granted by 'p4 protect'.

        The -p flag creates an attribute with a value that is propagated
        when the file is opened with 'p4 add', 'p4 edit', or 'p4 delete'.

        The -i flag causes the attribute value to be read from the standard
        input. Only one file argument is allowed when using this option.

        Multiple attributes can be set or cleared by specifying multiple
        '-n name' flags and an equal number of corresponding '-v value'
        flags (to set) or no '-v' flags (to clear).

        'p4 attribute -p' is not supported for files in a pending change
        from an edge server in a distributed environment.
```

Attributes are set per-revision, so they're actually tied to the history of the file.  One of the standard uses of attributes is to implement thumbnailing, by running a daemon (P4Thumb) that computes thumbnails for each revision and then attaches them to that revision as a small binary attribute.

When an attribute is set as "propagating", it will automatically be copied into the next revision every time you edit or integrate the file, so once you set an attribute its value will propagate to all later revisions of the file (including renames, copies, merge targets, etc) unless someone explicitly changes or removes it.

Here's how setting a "keywords" attribute on a file might look:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit puppies.jpg
//depot/puppies.jpg#1 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test>p4 attribute -p -n "keywords" -v "cute doggo" puppies.jpg
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/puppies.jpg#1 - keywords set

C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "adding keywords"
Submitting change 183.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //depot/puppies.jpg#2
Change 183 submitted.
```

The `p4 fstat -Oa` command will output attributes, and you can use the `-F` flag to filter based on the `attr-keywords` field that exists on files with that attribute:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 fstat -Oa -F "attr-keywords=*doggo*" ...
... depotFile //depot/puppies.jpg
... clientFile c:\Perforce\test\puppies.jpg
... isMapped
... headAction edit
... headType binary
... headTime 1596298248
... headRev 2
... headChange 183
... headModTime 1596298185
... haveRev 2
... attr-keywords cute doggo
... attrProp-keywords
```

Note that this is **not** an indexed search like what you get with `p4 index` and `p4 search` -- the `fstat` command is pulling all the files matching the filespec argument, and then the `-F` flag is *post-processing* the results before giving them to you, so it's liable to perform poorly if you're operating on something like a million files (but it should still be much faster than `p4 grep`, since it's entirely a db operation rather than requiring archive access).

Since the attribute is a single blob, implementing a single "keywords" attribute would mean that if you want to append to it, you'll need to read the current attribute, add to it, and then set the new blob -- it's not going to tokenize the inputs into individual words the way that "p4 index" will, and since it's a single blob you'll need to use the usual string wildcards if you want to match on a single word within that blob (like I did above with `*doggo*`).

Comment: Thanks, attribute -p looks more like what I want. But I can't find documentation of how attributes work, conceptually. Is there anything more than the bare mechanics of the commands? /// Here are some questions I want to answer. /// fstat doc lists "field names" which appear to be possible attribute values. Is it a closed set, or can I make up my own? /// Can I set a file's attribute multiple times, i.e. to multiple values? /// Do attribute values have a length limit? /// Can an attribute value be an arbitrary string? (Index is limited to single words, which I find rather shocking!)

Comment: Added an example of how you'd use `p4 attribute` to implement the same keyword search.

Comment: To answer some of the side questions -- you can give attributes arbitrary names and arbitrary values.  There's probably some upper limit to how huge an attribute can be, but they're designed to hold stuff like image data so you're unlikely to hit any such limit with your keyword use case.  :)  An attribute only has a single value, so if you want multiple pieces of data in a value, you'll need that value to serialize that data somehow.  In my example I just used space-separated words to keep the querying simple, but you could use CSV, JSON, whatever.

Comment: I reread your first reply & saw that it answered some of my questions. But puzzles remain. I entered ``p4 -n topic -v "<some text>" <filename>`` (valid filename in current directory) & got "Perforce client error... Invalid option: -n." Ditto when I put "topic" in quotes as you did. I concluded that I *can't* define my own attributes. But your "keyword" example isn't in the doc, so it apparently *is* user-defined. /// I can't find attribute support in p4v. We use p4v almost exclusively, so if it won't set attributes, getting file creators to specify them will be very hard!

Comment: Why did you use the command `topic` instead of `attribute` and why did you put the `-n` before the command instead of after it?

Comment: Confirmed that there's no attribute support in P4V, other than thumbnail support; attributes are more of a way for your to build your own extensions than an end-user thing.  Using change triggers might be a way you could expose a "setter" interface via P4V; come up with a convention to specify keywords in a change description and have a trigger that scrapes them from the description and sets them as attributes, so it's easy for file creators to add keywords at submit time.  Searching might make more sense to do via a custom-built web UI rather than P4V.

Comment: I actually implemented something very similar to this once upon a time to have keywords in change descriptions, although it didn't involve attributes or a trigger; I just built a web UI (as a plugin to our intranet wiki) that could show a list of changelists organized according to a defined set of keywords in change descriptions, so we could "tag" changes as "fix", "feature", etc.  https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/changes/7758

Comment: Oops. I was *trying* to execute ``p4 attribute``; topic was the attribute name. But I left out the verb, and stared at the command several times without seeing the problem. /// I tried again & found that a file must be open before an attribute can be set. Not a problem, but I don't want to try it until I have a "real" reason to open and commit a file... probably tomorrow. /// I can set attributes through P4V by writing a custom tool. I've never done that but one of my team members has. I can add further enhancements too, e.g. selecting keywords from a menu.

Comment: You can set an attribute on a submitted revision with the `-f` flag; like most commands that operate on already-submitted content, that requires `admin` permission.  For the purposes of experimentation I'd recommend just using a test server (it costs nothing to run `p4 init` in an empty directory) so you can play around and get an idea for how the final workflow will work; you don't want to be debugging it in production!  :)